# Is there any network collision in Rinkeby?

Tags: contract-development, mist, rinkeby

Am trying to deploy a test contract which is not getting mined and added. Trying for more than 2 days now, used the mist wallet to create it, chosen the highest price as per the mist wallet slider, but still not get updated. Is there any network congestion? Seems the main network also very slow in terms of blocks getting mined. Hope ethereum is good with its latest fork.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what was the issue. Maybe someone cleared it or so (after seeing this question, not sure though), All my pending transactions went thru now, and all of them are deployed.